# Materials from Imported FBX are incomplete

Tags: texturing, materials

First of all, sorry if there's an answer for this question anywhere but I decided to ask this and get personal help as I can't solve it with other's issues. Well, recently I ripped 3d models from Fate/Extella PC game. They're in fbx format.

[image: Left view still has material on it, the right one is what shows when it's erased]

This is one of the models from game. Within the game files there are some png textures, and all of them (but the normals) are at half opacity. As can be seen, his body doesn't fit with the texture, so it must be that there's some material completing the texture. I tried removing it and the result is that seen at right, as it should be. What I need is them together, as an image file that I can use. I also tried baking but the result is this.

[image: The output is this black image]

It means that material is empty, as I think, but also it's "supporting" the texture. Sorry, it's hard to explain in english when you're spanish. I need help with this, any suggestion is accepted. However, if anyone has time enough to try it, he can download the .blend file here (http://www.mediafire.com/file/k0n3j3hkm4rjt4e/Karna.blend).

Anyway, thanks to all of you!

Comment: Sorry, you expect to get help ripping content from commercial games? Materials aren't usually compatible between 3D formats so you're out of luck. Maybe you should ask the developers of the game for the models if you have a legitimate use.

Comment: its going to be really hard to help, because we do not know how the game set up its materials.